# Sort array ascending with zero at the end in Swift

Tags: arrays, sorting

How can I sort an array ascending with zero at the end in swift

```
let score = [3,0,4,6]
let ranking = score.sorted{ $0 < $1 }
```

I get :

```
ranking = [0,3,4,6]
```

I want :

```
ranking = [3,4,6,0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace any `0` encountered with a large number like `Int.max` in the `areInIncreasingOrder` predicate parameter for **[sorted](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchedresults/3364037-sorted)**:

```
let score = [3, 0, 4, 6]
let ranking = score.sorted{ ($0 == 0 ? Int.max : $0) < ($1 == 0 ? Int.max : $1) }
print(ranking)
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 4, 6, 0]
```

Comment: Thank You for your help

Comment: No problem it is a great question :)